# Cross-Origin Request Blocked for missing CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’

Tags: docker, nginx, cors

I have a UI running locally where I call the remote resource `arg.kl.com`. I hosted the UI on an nginx container with the configuration below. But still I am getting the warning above in the browser console. Not sure what is wrong in this config.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
}

location /folders/ {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    proxy_pass arg.kl.com;
}
```

}

I am seeing the following error in console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://arg.kl.com:4010/layouts/MV672Scse0-8663-40d8-876d-f.mvhtml.
>   (Reason: missing token ‘access-control-allow-headers’ in CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

What is wrong here?

Comment: The browser console message indicates the browser is sending a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before trying the actual request from your frontend UI code. So you need to make your nginx config send the correct CORS headers for responses to OPTIONS requests too. See https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html. Basically you probably want to add an `if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') { … }` block.

Comment: I tried with that block but it has no impact at all.